Buildling emqtt an SDK for emqx
I have downloaded emqtt from https://github.com/emqx/emqtt to use as a SDK client for EMQX. EMQX for Debian 10 can be downloaded from https://www.emqx.io/downloads?os=Debian
When I run "make" to build emqtt I get the following error
erlang@4diac:~/emqtt-master$ make
/usr/local/bin/rebar3 compile
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling emqtt
make: *** [Makefile:23: compile] Error 1

The error states that there is something wrong with line 23 in the Makefile that comes with emqtt when you clone it from git hub or download its zip file. I have made a copy of it show below
File: /home/erlang/emqtt-master/Makefile
01: CT_NODE_NAME = ct@127.0.0.1
02:
03: REBAR ?= $(or $(shell which rebar3 2>/dev/null),$(CURDIR)/rebar3)
04:
05: REBAR_URL := https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/releases/download/3.19.0/rebar3
06:
07: export REBAR_GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS += --depth=1
08:
09: all: emqtt
10:
11: $(REBAR):
12: curl -fsSL "$(REBAR_URL)" -o $@
13: chmod +x $@
14:
15: emqtt: $(REBAR) escript
16: $(REBAR) as emqtt release
17:
18: pkg: escript
19: $(REBAR) as emqtt_pkg release
20: make -C packages
21:
22: compile: $(REBAR)
23: $(REBAR) compile
24:
25: unlock:
26: $(REBAR) unlock
27:
28: clean: distclean
29:
30: distclean:
31: @rm -rf _build _packages erl_crash.dump rebar3.crashdump rebar.lock emqtt_cli rebar3
32:
33: xref:
34: $(REBAR) xref
35:
36: eunit: compile
37: $(REBAR) eunit verbose=true
38:
39: ct: compile
40: $(REBAR) as test ct -v --name $(CT_NODE_NAME)
41:
42: cover:
43: $(REBAR) cover
44:
45: test: eunit ct cover
46:
47: dialyzer:
48: $(REBAR) dialyzer
49:
50: escript: $(REBAR) compile
51: $(REBAR) as escript escriptize
52:
53: relup-test: ${REBAR}
54: bin/appup_test.sh

On my Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) machine I previously installed the following version of Erlang/OTP
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]
and also rebar3 which appears under
/usr/local/bin/rebar3
Perhaps the problem maybe because I have rebar3 already installed, but I can’t there being some kind software conflict here. Could someone from Stack Overflow help me resolve this problem.
To try to get closer to the problem i run make under root and got this error message
root@4diac:/home/erlang/emqtt-master# make/usr/local/bin/rebar3 compile===> Verifying dependencies...===> Upgrading gun (from {git,"https://github.com/emqx/gun",               {ref,"4faea40b9a8ca1eac5288355f8202e0cea379d50"}})===> Failed to fetch and copy dep: {git,"https://github.com/emqx/gun",                                  {ref,                                      "4faea40b9a8ca1eac5288355f8202e0cea379d50"}}make: *** [Makefile:23: compile] Error 1

In the rebar.conf file under the emqtt-master directory gun has a dependency on the cowlib
{deps, [{cowlib, "2.12.1"},
        {gun, {git, "https://github.com/emqx/gun", {tag, "1.3.7"}}},
        {getopt, "1.0.2"}
       ]}.

And in the rebar.lock file the version of gun is locked as a dependency to the version of cowlib
{"1.2.0",[{<<"cowlib">>,{pkg,<<"cowlib">>,<<"2.12.1">>},0}, {<<"getopt">>,{pkg,<<"getopt">>,<<"1.0.2">>},0}, {<<"gun">>,  {git,"https://github.com/emqx/gun",       {ref,"4faea40b9a8ca1eac5288355f8202e0cea379d50"}},  0}, {<<"quicer">>,  {git,"https://github.com/emqx/quic.git",       {ref,"06ac82db54dd1cb9576ac55f8f9abfefb266d683"}},  0}, {<<"snabbkaffe">>,{pkg,<<"snabbkaffe">>,<<"1.0.9">>},1}]}.[{pkg_hash,[ {<<"cowlib">>, <<"A9FA9A625F1D2025FE6B462CB865881329B5CAFF8F1854D1CBC9F9533F00E1E1">>}, {<<"getopt">>, <<"33D9B44289FE7AD08627DDFE1D798E30B2DA0033B51DA1B3A2D64E72CD581D02">>}, {<<"snabbkaffe">>, <<"A5027E088434C2CF045AC6983DC4F898DFEB317EC616D2BB2B7C82B81FEF71E4">>}]},{pkg_hash_ext,[ {<<"cowlib">>, <<"163B73F6367A7341B33C794C4E88E7DBFE6498AC42DCD69EF44C5BC5507C8DB0">>}, {<<"getopt">>, <<"A0029AEA4322FB82A61F6876A6D9C66DC9878B6CB61FAA13DF3187384FD4EA26">>}, {<<"snabbkaffe">>, <<"4D46C39C15BF989DAFD990D0CBC14027BDD3CB72468A51FB76363997C1B42275">>}]}].

Could there be a problem with rebar3 getting the wrong version of gun for cowlib? I have never used rebar3 and neither git to this level in order to debug the problem myself so if anyone has more understanding about this please let me know what to do.

Please, use multiline code formatting for several lines of code. Formatting each line separately only makes your code to consume larger part of the screen. Multiline code formatting could be achieved e.g. by adding lines with triple backticks before and after the content of the code.

Downloading the zip file to build the emqtt client for emqx does not work. Cloning the repository however does work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
